# How are quantifiers ordered when written at the end of an expression?

Tags: notation, quantifiers

I'm very familiar with boolean quantifiers when written at the beginning of an expression like so:

$$
\forall x: \exists y: P(x,y)
$$

However I've also seen the convention to write boolean quantifiers at the end. My question is do these conventions translate to one another by shifting like this:

$$
\forall x: \exists y: P(x,y)\quad \equiv\quad P(x,y)\quad\forall x\ \exists y
$$

or by reflection like this:

$$
\forall x: \exists y: P(x,y)\quad \equiv\quad P(x,y)\quad \exists y\ \forall x\ ?
$$

Comment: Quantifiers should **not** be written at the end. I've seen people do that on this site, but that's because they don't know any better.

Comment: Well, I've seen my professors do it routinely, even in written manuscripts. That said I can't recall them ever using alternating quantifiers within a single expression.

Comment: In logic, always put the quantifiers first. In less formal writing, a $\forall x$ afterwards might be considered acceptable (if one isn't too much of a fundamentalist), although “for all $x$” written out in words looks better. But $\exists y$ afterwards looks very strange indeed, and mixtures ever worse.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen an example where there are *multiple* quantifiers on the right side. The only such usage I am aware of is using one "$\forall$" at the end of a expression. $$f(x) = 0 \, \forall x.$$

This usually done to make things easier to read out loud. Here an example:

$$\forall \epsilon >0 :\exists \delta >0 :\forall x \in B_{x_0}(\delta) : |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon$$

This could be read as: *"For an arbitrary positive number epsilon there is a number delta such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $y$ within $\delta$ of $x_0$."*

So you could write this as *"...$|f(x)-f(x_0)| \leq \epsilon \forall y \in B_{x_0}(\delta)$"*

So this appended "$\forall$" is to be read as the last quator before the expression if you want to stick to the technical rules.

PS: I'm not justifying this notation, I just want to explain how it is usually used.